# socket закрывает соединение после получения ответа

Tags: python

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.0.106', 4444))
sock.send('hello'.encode())

data = sock.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

Есть у меня вот такой код.
Приложение конектится к тсп серверу отправляет hello, сервер отправляет ответ,
клиент получает ответ и закрывает соединение. Почему клиент закрывает соединение, как продолжить обмен?

Comment: А почему он должен его не закрывать, если у вас программа на этом завершается?

Comment: вы предлагаете зациклить?

Comment: Зацикли) если recv вернет пустую строку - выход из цикла

Comment: Похожий вопрос, ключевое слов в  Google - "keep alive" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110911/python-sockets-keep-socket-alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import socket sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.0.106', 4444)) 
sock.send('hello'.encode()) 
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    if not data: break
```